# Removing a item from a list and updating it python

Tags: python, list

i have a game where the player selects a challenge from a list:

```
locallist = ['Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)', 'Bella, the flourist (2)', 'Caitlyn, the painter(3)', 'Daniel, the scientist (4)', 'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']
```

after each challenge, i reprint the list so that they can pick another challenge, im looking for it to print a list not including the persons challenge that they just did.

Thanks for any insight

Comment: what the user input?? integer??

Comment: Do you want to remove an item from the list, or leave the list intact but print it with a specified element left out?

Comment: user input is integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use remove or pop depending on how the user chooses:

```
locallist = ['Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)', 'Bella, the flourist (2)', 'Caitlyn, the painter(3)', 'Daniel, the scientist (4)', 'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']

pick = 'Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)'
locallist.remove('Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)')
print(locallist)

pick = 1
locallist.pop(1)
print(locallist)

['Bella, the flourist (2)', 'Caitlyn, the painter(3)', 'Daniel, the scientist (4)', 'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']
['Bella, the flourist (2)', 'Daniel, the scientist (4)', 'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']
```

If you want to keep the original list intact, copy `locallist`:

```
remaining = locallist[:]
pick = 'Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)'
remaining.remove('Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)')
print(remaining)

pick = 1
remaining.pop(1)
print(remaining )

['Bella, the flourist (2)', 'Caitlyn, the painter(3)', 'Daniel, the scientist (4)', 'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']
['Bella, the flourist (2)', 'Daniel, the scientist (4)', 'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']
```

using `pop` will also give you the value so you can use it if needed:

```
pick = 1
challenge = remaining.pop(1)
print("You chose the following challenge: {}".format(challenge))
You chose the following challenge: Bella, the flourist (2)
```

Comment: @Hackaholic, I have covered both scenarios

Comment: @hennessyd, no worries

Answer (score 0):

You could create set from the original list. Then remove picked item from set and print set.